# Several general questions about Sony Ericsson Live View

Tags: htc-sensation, sony-ericsson-live-view

First does it have an acceleration, compass, or "gyroscope".

Second can it make noises?

Third does it work for HTC Sensation?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Sony Ericsson website, the [Live View specs page](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/accessories/overview/liveviewmicrodisplay?cc=gb&lc=en#view=features_specifications) has no mention of a compass, gyroscope, accelerometer or similar. It doesn't mention anything about speakers either but does mention controlling phone calls and music playback on your phone, which would suggest its not designed to make noise itself but to control the music/sound on a phone (or other compatible device) that it's connected to.

The [compatible phones page (other brands)](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/accessories/overview/liveviewmicrodisplay?cc=gb&lc=en#view=compatible_phones) lists a number of HTC phones, but not the Sensation. It does however say:

> Compatible with most other brands on Android 2.0 and up that are
>   equipped with Bluetooth™ 2.1.

According to [HTC's Specs page for the Sensation](http://www.htc.com/www/smartphones/htc-sensation/#specs) it has Bluetooth v3.0 compatibility, so it is likely that it will work with the Live View.